# count api usages of jquery. how is my jquery used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I would like to get rid of jQuery, replace its selector with querySelector and use micro-frameworks to do specific things (mostly ajax requests).

In order to evaluate the quantity of calls that are actually made to its api. How many `$.ajax()` calls, how many `.not()` selectors, how many `.closest()`selectors are called.

The codebase is huge, messy and undocumented, should I go with a regex parser ? a custom jquery plugin ? a profiling software ?

How should I represent the result ? a usage list ? an api tree ?

Comment: If you have the jquery lib locally, why not put a count in the jquery lib its self every time those methods are used?

Comment: @atmd is there a "clean" way to do it other than adding a bit of code in each jQuery method to increment a counter?

Answer (score 0):

you may find out how often  $.ajax() is used by  listening on

```
$.ajaxStart(function(e) {
    console.log("request made"); console.dir(e)
});
```

only if global property of call itself is not false